# How can I compile my own copy of Swift from source for Raspbian

Tags: swift, raspberry-pi

I see that I can get a pre-built version of Swift 4.1.2 from swift-arm.com: [Swift 4.1.2 Updated For RaspberryPi 2/3](https://swift-arm.com/2018/08/02/swift-4-1-2-updated-for-raspberrypi-2-3/)

However, I'm inherently distrusting of anonymously posted binaries, and would like to understand how I can build it myself.

I also want (or think I want) to keep using Raspbian, rather than switch to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to https://github.com/uraimo/buildSwiftOnARM you will find all the info you need to build your own Swift on Raspbian.

There is also an updated Repository for Swift installs on Arm Devices including the Raspberry Pi. - https://swift-arm.com/2019/01/07/official-swift-arm-community-releases/
The Raspbian builds on the repo are from uraimo that I have packaged myself.
I understand your "inherently distrusting" but these are not anonymously posted binaries but the work of the "swift on arm" community.
You are welcome to join the swift-arm slack and talk to the people doing the building. They are more than happy to help you achieve your own builds.
https://launchpass.com/swift-arm

Neil.